# Correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, correlation

I'm a little puzzled by the whole random variable thing.

I've got two random variables, $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{N}$, both with gaussian distribution with mean = 0 and $\sigma_{\mathcal{X}}^2$ and $\sigma_{\mathcal{N}}^2$ respectively.

The equation for correlation coefficient is

$$
\rho_{XY} = E\left[\frac{X-E[X]}{\sigma_{\mathcal{X}}}\frac{Y-E[Y]}{\sigma_{\mathcal{N}}}\right]
$$

I know how to find $E$ but what value do $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ actually have that I plug into the equation?

Comment: The thing inside $[\cdot]$ is another random variable, and $E$ denotes its expectation value. You're not supposed to plug in any single values of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: The trouble is that that $E$ is an expectation over $X$ and $Y$ jointly. You need, e.g., the covariance as well to be able to calculate the correlation.

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate an expectation ($E$) of a random variable $Z$ you sum up for all values of $Z$ times the respective prbability of $Z$ taking that value. Accordingly, you work here. So every possible value of $X,Y$ will apper (be plugged) in the equation, multiplied however with the repsective probability of occuring ([see formula of expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)).

If you know that two random variables are independent then that implies that they are uncorrelated. ([independent implies uncorrelated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated) but not the other way round). So in that case $$\rho_{XY}=0$$
and you do not need to apply the definition nor do any calculations to prove it.

Comment: is the coefficient not simply zero?

Since $E[\frac{XY}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}] = 0$

Comment: They are independent, I failed to note that in my initial post. What does that tell us?

Comment: Well now he assigned the same problem, but with the correction that we should calculate the correlation coefficient of X and Y.

Comment: X and N are independent but Y = X + N

Comment: @user2750354 Write correctly the question and you will get a reasonable answer.... You are changing all the time

Comment: @user2750354 Look at my other answer. That is what you want!